# Need help making a list for my programming 101 class

Tags: list, python-3.x

im new to programming and my programming assignment wants me to Create a 'list' called my_numbers which contains the odd numbers between 0 and 100 using a for-loop and I am trying to figure out how I can make a list and add 2 to the number in front of it and keep repeating. here is my code so far in python 3.5, thanks in advance to anyone who answers.

```
    my_numbers = [1]
    for i in range (0,100):
        my_numbers = my_numbers + [2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your solution is:

```
my_numbers = range(1, 100, 2)
```

`1` - start of range, inclusive

`100` - end of range, non-inclusive

`2` - step

Or in a for loop:

```
a = []
for x in range(1, 100):
    if x % 2 == 1:
        a.append(x)
```

Or in plain words:

For every number between 1 and 100, if you divide that number with 2 and have a reminder of 1 then add that number to the list.

Comment: thank you, makes it seem so much easier than I thought.